# Shifting row values for multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, row, multiple-columns, shift

I have the following dataframe:

```
xR <- data.frame("A" = c(15, 13.5, 12, 9.1, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
             "B" = c(NA, 13.6, 8.4, 6.7, 5.6, 2.0, NA, NA), 
             "C" = c(NA, NA, 8.5, 2.43, 1.23, NA, NA, NA))
```

How do I shift the rows in columns B and C up by 1 row to get:

```
xR1 <- data.frame("A" = c(15, 13.5, 12, 9.1, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
             "B" = c(13.6, 8.4, 6.7, 5.6, 2.0, NA, NA, NA), 
             "C" = c(NA, 8.5, 2.43, 1.23, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

My dataframe has 100+ columns so trying to automate it.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Write a function that does the shifting `shift_1 <- function(x) c(x[-1], x[1])` and apply it to your data `xR[, cols] <- lapply(xR[, cols], shift_1)`, where `cols` is a character vector of column names, i.e. `cols <- c("B", "C")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *base* you can use `[-1]` to skip the first element and `c` with `NA` to add `NA` at the end:

```
data.frame(xR[1], lapply(xR[-1], function(x) c(x[-1], NA)))
#     A    B    C
#1 15.0 13.6   NA
#2 13.5  8.4 8.50
#3 12.0  6.7 2.43
#4  9.1  5.6 1.23
#5   NA  2.0   NA
#6   NA   NA   NA
#7   NA   NA   NA
#8   NA   NA   NA
```

or modification in place using the thoughts from @Ricardo:

```
xR[,-1] <- rbind(xR[-1,-1], NA)
xR
#     A    B    C
#1 15.0 13.6   NA
#2 13.5  8.4 8.50
#3 12.0  6.7 2.43
#4  9.1  5.6 1.23
#5   NA  2.0   NA
#6   NA   NA   NA
#7   NA   NA   NA
#8   NA   NA   NA
```

or only using sub-setting:

```
xR[,-1] <- xR[seq_len(nrow(xR)) + 1, -1]
```

Comment: Aside from this @GKi- is it possible to shift col B up 1 row, col C up 2 rows and so on? Thanks

Comment: Try: `xR[,-1] <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(xR)-1), function(i) c(xR[-seq_len(i),i+1], rep(NA, i)))`

Comment: Final question @GKi - is it possible to shift values in Col B so that it starts on same row of Col A where first value of Col B is lower than Col A? Hope this makes sense. If not, I'll create an example - thanks

Comment: Maybe? `i <- which.max(!is.na(xR$B)); i <- i-which.max(xR$B[i] < xR$A); if(i > 0) c(xR$B[-seq_len(i)], rep(NA, i)) else xR$B`

Comment: Thanks @GKi - this didn't work - I've asked it as a separate question as I think it helps explain it better - thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

Using base R:

```
xR[,2:3] = rbind(xR[-1,2:3], NA)
```

Then you can change the `2:3` to all the columns that you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
xR1 <- xR %>%
  mutate(B = lead(B),
         C = lead(C))
```

which gives:

```
     A    B    C
1 15.0 13.6   NA
2 13.5  8.4 8.50
3 12.0  6.7 2.43
4  9.1  5.6 1.23
5   NA  2.0   NA
6   NA   NA   NA
7   NA   NA   NA
8   NA   NA   NA
```

Automating across many columns (assuming you don't want to do the shifting for column A) is quite easy:

```
xR1 <- xR %>%
  mutate(across(-A, lead))
```

Comment: Thanks @deschen but I have many many columns so not sure how to do it for every column. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can automate this across a wide selection of columns with

```r
xR %>% 
  dplyr::mutate_at(.vars = vars(B:C),
                   .funs = ~ dplyr::lead(.x, 1))
```